# Duplicate Arduino SD Library

Tags: sd.h

I need to have two independent arduino sd libraries so that I can modify one and have the other one intact. I struggle to do so.
Does anyone know if this is even possible?
What should be the path to properly do so?

I tried a lot of things but I always end up in a spot where I dont know what code is working and what is not. Last try I duplicated all the files and renambed all the functions to whatever"2" but couldn't make it work

Comment: What is the background of your project? Do you want to use both libraries in the same sketch? If so, why? What requirements do you have? Please [edit] your question and add these informations, don't use comments.

Comment: Do you need to use both of them insifde the same project?

Comment: If not then just create the library folder and copy it within the project where you are editing it Then include it as `#include "Sd.h"` rather then `#include "Sd.h"`

Comment: Yes I need to use them both inside the same project

Comment: If your objective is to use 2 SD card readers (pseudo) simultaneously in a project then this may help: https://forum.arduino.cc/t/two-sd-cards-on-the-same-project/1012605

Comment: that wont work, I need two independent sd libraries on the same sketch

Comment: You urgently need to add your goal to the question by [edit]ing it. Don't let us and future viewers pick up all the details like bread crumbs from your comments. -- Do you want the two different libraries access the same SD card or two different SD cards? -- Does you project build the libraries from source, or does it use ready-built libraries?

Comment: @the-busybee Quote from post "I need to have two independent arduino sd libraries so that I can modify one and have the other one intact." Quote from title "Duplicate Arduino SD Library"

Comment: Well, I'm giving up. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use two SD card than instead of copying the whole library just create another instance of the class like

```
SDClass SD2;
```

Now you can call SD2.begin(CS_PIN_2) or any other function of the sd library.

Comment: That wont work because you are using the same library just changing the name where you call it. I need two independent libraries

Comment: Why do you _need_ two independent libraries? Are you aware that the variables of both objects of `SDClass` are already independent?

Comment: @Espada86 Why you want two libraries? Because you want to use two SD cards ?

Comment: @the-busybee the requierement is to have two independent libraries because I want to modify one and have the other one unchanged but being able to call any of them on the same sketch.

Comment: @Espada86 Can you give a hint what you want to change in the library ?

Comment: @Espada86, use one modified library. modify it that way so it can be used the unmodified way too